# How to assign permissions of a user in a table to another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I'm trying to solve a problem about permissions of a user in my homework.

Consider, I have these tables:

```
User(UserName, Password, GroupID) -- Stores User account
Group(GroupID, GroupName) -- could be Admin, User
```

and i have a table:

```
Product(ProductID, ProductName) -- Stores products info
```

Can I set permissions of a user in table User to table Product?

Ex: table User has two user account: John, Joan
John can insert, update, delete on table Product
but Joan can only Select the products on table Product.